# firebase add user information while creating user (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I researched before asking this question but I couldn't find an answer.

I made a form in react js. When I click the button it creates a user with createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method. There is no problem with creating the user. I want to add extra information like; username : "Usernameeeee" to my database. The database will look like this:

```
users {
     userUid1: {name: "Name User 1"}
     userUid2: {name: "Name User 2"}
     ....
       }
```

When I use createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), it creates a user and logs them in. But as you can see the above, I need the current user's id. I know how to get it normally, firebase.auth().currenUser... But while creating a user I can't catch the user's id. It returns null;

```
export function signUpUser({email, password}) {
return function (dispatch){
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(
    () => dispatch({type: USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS})
)
.then(console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser))
.catch(error => {
    dispatch({type: USER_SIGNUP_FAIL, payload: error.message});
});
}
```

}

When I console the current user, the creating user is complete but not logged in yet. So how can I add information while creating a user ? (not after logged in some other way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer after a day. I hope this will be helpful to others. As you understand, the main problem is getting the user id right after creating a user, before user sign in...

So the solution is:

```
export function signUpUser({email, password, username}) {
    const db = firebase.database();
    return function (dispatch){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      // here we get user id if creating is successful.
    .then(function(user){
        dispatch({type: USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS}); // I dispatched some message.
        db.ref(`users/${user.uid}`).set({name: username}); // I added user
        console.log('uid:',user.uid)

})
```